# Carrying liquor on transit from Germany

Tags: transit, germany, alcohol, duty-free

I'm travelling from Frankfurt to India next week. I wanted to buy some good liquor for friends back home. I want to know what is cheaper -- to buy in Franfurt duty free stores or in some good liquor stores in Germany. And also, is there anything specific/exotic liquor that I can buy in Germany?

EDIT: I hope this is more on topic -- I want to know if its OK if I buy liquor at the Frankfurt airport I'll be allowed to carry it in my cabin luggage when I switch planes in Colombo (obviously I'll be allowed to carry in from Frankfurt to Colombo). Also, I don't have to change terminals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duty free is normally cheaper, because it has no duties on the items.

German speciality liquors are Kirschwasser, Zwetschgenwasser (it is not water; it is a clear distillate), or the infamous Jägermeister (which is a bitter). There are also several monasteries who produce their own liquor (in the label you would find "Kloster").

Comment: Can I find Kirschwasser, Zwetschgenwasser in the Frankfurt duty-free? Jagermeister, I'm sure I have seen there.

Comment: I can not confirm, but an educated guess is that you should be able to find it; maybe in a "regional specialities" section.